# Import function from imported module

Tags: python

I have a module with a long name. I want to import some functions from it, using `from ... import ...` syntax. I tried to make these imports shorter, using `import ... as ...` trick, but it didn't work.
Why this example doesn't work?

```
>>> import long_named_module as spam
>>> from spam import func
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named spam
```

Comment: `from [module] import [function] as [alias]`

Comment: The problem is that the [module] name in this sentence is too long.
I don't want to write: "
from long_named_module import func;
from long_named_module import func2"
...
I want to write: "
from spam import func;
from spam import func2"

Comment: `import long_named_module as spam; short_name = spam.func`

Comment: That is not what I want.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do that is:

```
import long_named_module as spam
func = spam.func
```

Comment: *"That is not what I want."* – Timur !?

Answer (score 0):

```
from long_named_module import func1, func2, func3
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how it answers the question would significantly improve its long-term value. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation.